Report formula for Over90Days
What is the purpose of the 'Over90Days' function in Crystal Reports?
{CreatedDate} Over90Days
When I use this function in my report, it returns records from the past 120 days instead of the expected 90 days. What is the equivalent expression in SSRS to return previous 90 days of records?

As MilletSoftware pointed out, Over90Days means exactly that, anything over 90 days, not "over the last 90 days".
In SSRS you would typically do this as part of the dataset query in the WHERE clause, something like
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATEDIFF(d, myDateColumn, getdate()) <= 90

This is usually the best way as it reduces the amount of data being sent to the report, rather than sending thousands of rows, and then filtering the results later.
Alternativley, if you have no control over the query, you can add a filter expression to the dataset filters collection.
Set the expression to something like
=DATEDIFF(dateinterval.Day, Fields!myDateColumn.Value, today())<=90

Set the expression type to Boolean , the operator to = and the value to true


Thank you for the quick response.  The SQL query retruns 420 rows:
Where DATEDIFF(d, CACOMPUTEDFEE.CREATEDON, getdate()) <= 90.
Crystal report retruns 943 rows: {fees_past_due;1.CREATEDON} in Over90Days
since migrating to SSRS, planning to update Stored proc so that it matches and returns the same amount of rows as in CR.  Please help

Create a new question and include sample data, results, expressions, queries that you are using. If this answer answered your initial question ,please mark it as accepted (the check mark to the left), this helps others find answers to similar question in the future.

Also, note that, as mentioned before, CR Over90Days will returns rows older than 90 days, which is not what you said you wanted in your question, the query and expression I put in my answer will give you anything in the last 90 days - so the number of rows will be different. You could easily replicate the CR functionality by changing <= to >= but that does not seem to be what you actually want.

Thanks, I had to do DATEDIFF(d, CACOMPUTEDFEE.CREATEDON, getdate()) >= 91.

In Crystal Reports, Over90Days specifies a range of Date values that includes all values that are more than 90 days older than the current date.
It sounds like you need the reverse logic. You can use DateDiff() or simply get the difference in days using CurrentDate - {CreatedDate}.
As to SSRS, try something like: [CreatedDate] between _add_days(current_date,-90) and current_date
